# Proving implications of equations

Tags: finance

I'm currently working on the finance problem:

If we define $I_k$ = A(k)-A(k-1) then $\sum_{k=1}^n I_k$ = A(n) - A(0)

show that this implies $\sum_{k=1}^n i_ka(k-1)$ = a(k)-1

So I know that our top equation is a telescoping sum, and every value will cancel out leaving just A(n) - A(0). Also, I know that a(n) = A(n)/A(0). Thus, we could makes a(k-1) A(k-1)/A(0) (and the same thing for the RHS). I just don't know where I should go from here in proving this equation? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand your question.  You state a hypothesis In terms of "A", but then ask about "a".  Are those the same?  And what is "[math]i_k[/math]?

Comment: @user247327 I don't know where you're seeing that... It's Math Jax and should show up as equations.

Comment: What are the meanings of all those variables ?